# Add overlay to expression 4 video

Tags: c#, video, expression, wmv

I am recording a live webfeed using the Expressions 4 libraries. They have been an absolute dream to use, with the small exception that i cannot seem to draw on top of the video using graphics.

I am trying to put a watermark in the corner, and add a time stamp to the top left corner. Previously i had been using Aforge and it worked well enough, but it is too much work to try and get audio into your video files(lengthy conversions BTC). Expressions gives me an easy way to capture both, but apparently at the expense of many key events.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a WPF canvas with Expression Design to use as an overlay. You can also animate it with Blend, though my experience is that not all animation types are honored.

Here's a link to a brief walkthrough of what to do: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/expressionencoder/archive/2008/07/01/8677762.aspx

Comment: I realize I can do that within Expression encoder, but I am making use of the Expression 4 Pro APIs. I need to be able to programmatically add a watermark to the video itself as its being recorded live from a web cam. The old way of recording makes it easy to draw GDI onto each individual frame, but it seems that the expression 4 APIs do not give you access to the FrameUpdate events, which would allow the injection of graphics onto each frame.